# Test if file exists and executed even at the time of submission

Tags: if-statement, file-upload, drupal-7, file-exists

I implemented a feature that tests if my file already exists; whether an error message is displayed and a pop up Java script. Otherwise it does nothing.
Except that at the time of registration of my content. He still enters the loop and as the file is already uploaded it still displays the error message and so I can never create my content.

In advance, thank you for your help.

```
function bportal_tesst_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 

    if ($form_id == 'document_node_form') { 
        $form['field_document_file']['und'][0]['#upload_validators']['custom_document_upload_validation'] = array();        
    }
    return $form;
}

function custom_document_upload_validation($file) {
$filename = $file->filename;
$errors = array();

    if (file_exists('/var/www/vhosts/BP/docroot/sites/default/files-private/documents/'.$filename)) {
        print_r($filename);
        $errors[] = t("The new file already exists. Please use a different name.");
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','bportal_tesst') . '/js/pop-in.js');
    }   
    return $errors;
}
```